# Bookmark Questions

Tags: support, bookmarks

Is there any way to Bookmark questions. so that we can bookmark interesting answers. I saw the favorite section in the User profile . Does this has to do with Bookmarks?

Answer (score 5):

You can click the star next to a question to mark it as a favorite. See also, [How do favorite questions work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53585/how-do-favorite-questions-work)